# Installing Mac OS X on a MacBook which has Windows 7 installed on it

Tags: mac

I just got this MacBook from my a friend, before getting it from him, he had changed the OS on it to Windows 7 a long time ago. Now I want to return the OS to a normal Macintosh OS, I don’t want to use windows on the PC anymore.

I got a Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) CD to re-install Mac OS X but am having serious issue doing this. Whenever I hold on <kbd>C</kbd> before startup, the screen remains blanks till am fed up and power off the PC myself.

Answer (score 1):

> I got a Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) CD to re-install Mac OS X but am having
>   serious issue doing this. Whenever I hold on <kbd>C</kbd> before
>   startup, the screen remains blanks till am fed up and power off the PC
>   myself.

Instead of holding down the <kbd>C</kbd> key try shutting down, starting up again and then holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key to start up via the “Starup Manager”—[as explained here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)—where you can select a Mac OS X volume or even a network volume to start from.

For more details on how the “Startup Manager” works, please refer to [the official Apple page on how it works and how you can use it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1310). In this case, these instructions are all—I am pretty sure—you will really need:

1. Turn on or restart your Mac.
2. Immediately press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key. After a few seconds, the “Startup Manager” appears. If you don’t see the volume you want to use, wait a few moments for Startup Manager to finish scanning connected drives.
3. Use your mouse or trackpad, or left and right arrow keys to select the volume you want to use.
4. Double-click or press the <kbd>return</kbd> key to start up your Mac from the volume you selected.